# Automapper для большого количества моделей

Tags: c#

Есть такая ситуация:

```
class A {
  protected string s1;
  protected string s2;
}

class A1 : A {
}

class A2 : A {
}

class A3 : A {
}



class B1 {
}

class B2 {
}

class B3 {
}
```

Нужно провести следующий мапинг: A1 -> B1, A2 -> B2, A3 -> B3 при этом игнорируя s1 и s2.
Проблема в том, что таких моделей как А і В около пятидесяти.

Как можна это сделать самым оптимальным путем?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кодогенерацией

Comment: Не сильно понял о чем Вьі.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/64895/